# How to view source code of NuGet dependencies (C#)

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I am developing an ASP.NET Core application and I would like to see source code of at least various System/Microsoft libraries, like `AspNetCore`.

I found [this article](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/debugging-asp-net-core-2-source) that explains how to debug them which forces Visual Studio to download Source code. What I would like is a way to see the source code without running an application, hitting a break-point and Stepping-In to view the source.

Is there a way?

Btw, I am on VS 2017, .Net Core 2.1

NOTE:
I am not looking for a way to decompile IL or some other magic trick. I would like Visual Studio to import the original Source Code files and display them to me when I want it without needing to go the full length of building, running in debug, need to hit a breakpoint.

Comment: Look up .NET Disassembler: there are number out there that will generate source code from the IL in a .NET assembly. (Also, VS 2017 has experimental support that can be enabled in the options and will disassemble when you go to reference).

Comment: You can browse to nuget.org and search for the package. Once you find the package.. you can locate the sourcecode URL for that package on the right side of the page. Example of NewtonSoft.Json package [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/12.0.1-beta1)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this VS extension from RedGate allows you to do exactly that.  I've used an older version of this tool and you just pointed it at a DLL and it gave you a class tree and decompiled code for the various functions.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-306627.NETReflectorVisualStudioExtension

Answer (score 0):

DnsSpy is good application to see code source inside dll for example

see [DnsSpy 86 or 64](https://github.com/0xd4d/dnSpy)

Answer (score 0):

Here is Microsoft github page where you can see source codes of .NET Framework classes. [Link](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource)

If you want to see code in Visual Studio, you can use DotPeek ([Link](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/?fromMenu))